# GAE and JPA persistence exception

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I've created a GAE 1.8.2 project using JPA 2.0. When i try to launch Junit tests it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at it.bfm.dbutility.DbAccess.<init>(DbAccess.java:10)
    at it.bfm.businesslogic.UtenteImpl.<init>(UtenteImpl.java:16)
    at it.bfm.test.UtenteTest.testCreaUtente(UtenteTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl, org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createPersistenceException(Persistence.java:242)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:184)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
    at it.bfm.dbutility.EntityBfmManager.<clinit>(EntityBfmManager.java:8)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jpa" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/Applications/Eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.2/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.2/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/Users/Stefano/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jpa/3.1.3/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar."
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:541)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:395)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensions(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:219)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensionPoints(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:160)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:65)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createPluginManager(PluginManager.java:427)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory.<init>(JPAEntityManagerFactory.java:328)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:91)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:150)
    ... 28 more
```

The Persistence.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.singletonEMFForName" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the pom.xml is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.bfm</groupId>
    <artifactId>bfm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>3.1.3</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-jsr107cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jsr107cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr107cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/it/bfm</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/it/bfm/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
<!--        <resources> -->
<!--            <resource> -->
<!--                <directory>${basedir}/src</directory> -->
<!--            </resource> -->
<!--        </resources> -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                        <webResources>
                            <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can someone help me please?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems very clear

> The URL
>   "file:/Applications/Eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.2/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.2/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar"
>   is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical
>   plugin located at URL 
>   "file:/Users/Stefano/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jpa/3.1.3/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar."

so suggest you put a single version of a jar in the CLASSPATH, otherwise you will get class loading problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, but the error that worries me is this:

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "transactions-optional" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl, org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl

Do you have any ideas about the possible solution?

Comment: fix the classpath as said, that message you mention is only thrown because of the bad classpath

Comment: Hi DataNucleus, I have created the GAE project with Google Eclipse plugin and later I have put it under maven management. So in the build path libraries i have (in order): App Engine SDK, JRE System Library and Maven Dependencies. Have I to delete App Engine SDK libraries?

Comment: @DataNucleus I also facing same problem.i checked my .classpath file but there is nothing duplicate version of jar.Can you help me where i did wrong?